# Searching XML using XPath for multiple attributes in php

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, xpath

I found same topics but I didn't solve my problem :(

I want to search in XML with product code

this is my code;

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.aksel.com.tr/Xml.aspx?SK=d021da08&CK=50288');
                    $product_code = $_GET['s'];
                    $products = $xml->xpath("//STOK_KODU[contains(text(), '".$product_code."')]/STOK_ADI/GRUPKODU");
```

if I remove "/STOKADI/GRUPKODU", its working. But Product title, product image, product category didn't show. Where is the problem?

And my second problem, when I want to show all products; I see some products at least 4-5 times.

(Note: I work in WordPress)

Comment: What is your `$product_code` that gives multiple products in return?

Comment: $product_code=$_GET['s']; return one product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `simple_xml` but the approach below, using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` should be easy enough to port to `simple_xml` if desired. Initially I thought you were looking for child nodes of `STOK_KODU` but the structure of the XML suggests otherwise. The XPath query will find the node with the relevant `$product_code` from which you can easily find the parent and thus any/all of it's children.

```
$file='http://xml.aksel.com.tr/Xml.aspx?SK=d021da08&CK=50288';
#$file='c:/temp/Xml.xml'; /* saved locally to test */

$output=array();
$product_code=13775;

$query='//XMLWEBDATA/STOK_KODU[ contains( text(), "'.$product_code.'"  ) ]';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $file );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( $query );

if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){

    foreach( $col as $node ){
        /* get the parent */
        $parent=$node->parentNode;

        $data=array();
        for( $i=0; $i < $parent->childNodes->length; $i++ ){

            $tag=$parent->childNodes->item( $i )->tagName;
            $value=$parent->childNodes->item( $i )->nodeValue;

            if( !empty( $tag ) && !empty( $value ) ) $data[ $tag ]=$value;
        }
        $output[]=$data;
    }

    /* remove duplicates if there are any */
    $output=array_unique( $output );
}
$xp = $dom = null;


/* process the results accordingly */
if( !empty( $output ) ){
    foreach( $output as $obj ){
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>', urldecode( http_build_query( $obj, null, PHP_EOL ) ) );
    }
}
```

The output of which will be

```
STOK_KODU=13775
STOK_ADI=CHIP EPSON C3800 Black (S051127)
LISTEFIYAT=2,73
STOKBAKIYE1=16
GRUPKODU=DOLUM ÜRÜNLERİ GRUBU
KOD1=TONER DOLUM ÜRÜNLERİ
KOD2=ÇİPLER
PARABIRIMI=$
KULL5N=9500
RESIMURL=http://xml.aksel.com.tr/Photo.aspx?ID=22705&STOK=13775
```

---

To access each field as a variable ( which is what I understand your comment to be )

```
foreach( $col as $node ){
    /* get the parent */
    $parent=$node->parentNode;

    $data=array();
    for( $i=0; $i < $parent->childNodes->length; $i++ ){
        try{
            /* test node type to avoid errors */
            if( $parent->childNodes->item( $i )->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ){

                $tag=$parent->childNodes->item( $i )->tagName;
                $value=$parent->childNodes->item( $i )->nodeValue;

                if( !empty( $tag ) && !empty( $value ) ) $data[ $tag ]=$value;
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            continue;
        }
    }
    $output[]=$data;
}
```

and to access as variables, use `extract`

```
            if( !empty( $output ) ){
                foreach( $output as $obj ){

                    extract( $obj );
                    printf("<pre>%s\n%s\n%s</pre>", $STOK_KODU, $STOK_ADI, $GRUPKODU );

                }
            }
```

Comment: hello, i get this result but how i get like variable.  

$stokadi = $obj->STOK_ADI;
$stokkodu = $obj->STOK_KODU;
$kategori = $obj->GRUPKODU;
$childkategori = $obj->KOD3;

not working

Comment: i try $stokadi = $obj->getElementsByTagName('STOK_ADI') but i get php fatal error Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object

Comment: last question :) xml url and some tags changed anyway..

<RESIM>
<RESIM URL="http://....">
<RESIM URL="http://....">

how i get url parameter.

I try getElementsByTagName, getAttributes but get php fatal error :(

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the structure of the XML, the GRUPKODU and STOKADI are elements at the same level.  So trying to access these in you XPath at the same time isn't going to work.  If instead you look for the XMLWEBDATA element your after, you can then access these elements inside this element.  This XPath looks for an XMLWEBDATA with a STOK_KODU with content that contains the product code your after, then using `foreach` to print out each match, it outputs the two values your after...

```
$products = $xml->xpath("//XMLWEBDATA[STOK_KODU[contains(text(), '".$product_code."')]]");
foreach ( $products as $product )   {
    echo (string)$product->STOK_ADI.PHP_EOL;
    echo (string)$product->GRUPKODU.PHP_EOL;
}
```

(I only cast the return values to strings as this is needed if assigning to other values, `echo` will automatically cast it anyway and it can cause confusing results when used in assignments)

If I set

```
$product_code = 14037;
```

This outputs

```
EPSON T2711XL (27XL) > WF3620,3640,7110,7610,7620  Black
TÜKETİM ÜRÜNLERİ GRUBU
```

Note: You may want to use....

```
$products = $xml->xpath("//XMLWEBDATA[STOK_KODU='".$product_code."']");
```

to ensure that you only find a code that fully matches in case there are cases where it will match parts of other codes.